# How to get a header value in a RestController and pass it to the parent controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services

I'm new to spring-boot and quite new to web services.

I would like to implement an authorization process in an (abstract) generic RestController which should get the content of the basic-auth. header from the extending controllers and then perform the authorization.

Something like that:

```
public class GenericController
{
  // Constructor 
  protected GenericController(String basicAuth) throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException
  {
    // check user can execute action
  }
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping( "/users" )
public class UserController extends GenericController
{
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);
  
  // Constructor
  protected UserController() throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException
  {
    // somehow get the basic auth information from header and pass it to the parent's constructor
    basicAuth = ???
    
    super(basicAuth);
  }

  @GetMapping( "/user/{cn}" )
  public String getUser( @PathVariable String cn )
  {
    logger.error("Start getUser(...): cn=" + cn);

  }
```

How can I do that? (is that even possible?)

ADDED INFORMATION:
My web services are themselves consumers of other web services.

Once the calling user is authorized to "use" my web services I have to forward/set the Basic Authentication into the request for the web services I call.

So, how/where can I "intercept" and get the headers when my services are called?

Comment: At the time you construct a `Controller`, you are not in a request context.  There are no headers to get (unless you're making a new instance on every request, which isn't the case with your current annotation set up, and is in general a horrible idea).  What exactly are you wanting to _do_ with this information, and why is it imperative that it happens at construction rather than when a request comes in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to take a look at [Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/) framework. There are many tutorials showing how to configure it to perform basic authentication, e.g.: [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication).

The main idea is decoupling authentication / authorization concerns from controllers and business logic code. To implement this filters are used which intercept every request and validate it against different conditions. When implementing stateless REST-service (each request independent from others) it's not so difficult. When handling sessions, logic will become much more complicated. Spring Security implements filter chains, consisting of multiple filters, each performing its own checks.

Spring Security is used very often in spring-based projects and is definitely worth to look at, although it may seem a bit difficult when meeting it for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpServletRequest to get the header from the request.

```
 protected UserController(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException
    {

        System.out.println( httpServletRequest.getHeaders("key name"));
        // somehow get the basic auth information from header and pass it to the parent's constructor
        basicAuth = ???

        super(basicAuth);
    }
```

Comment: I get the error:ERROR ...
Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file [...]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed;... No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.